# I'm stuck in a login loop

Tags: xorg, elementaryos, gnome-session

I'm running `elementaryOS` and I can login to every account except my main one. I've already tried deleting `.Xauthority` and even changing its permissions, but still no luck.

`.xsession-errors`:

```
Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"

** (gnome-session:23495): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-hQz2kj7UDd: Connection refused
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"

** (gnome-session-check-accelerated:23617): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-hQz2kj7UDd: Connection refused
gnome-session[23495]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file indicator-printers.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
gnome-session[23495]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file telepathy-indicator.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
gnome-session[23495]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file gnome-screensaver.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
gnome-session[23495]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file unity-settings-daemon.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
gnome-session[23495]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file unity-fallback-mount-helper.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
gnome-session[23495]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file deja-dup-monitor.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"

** (gnome-settings-daemon:23633): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-hQz2kj7UDd: Connection refused

(gnome-settings-daemon:23633): media-keys-plugin-WARNING **: Grab failed for some keys, another application may already have access the them.
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
Window manager warning: Log level 128: Settings.vala:163: Loading settings from schema 'org.gnome.desktop.background'
Window manager warning: Log level 128: Settings.vala:163: Loading settings from schema 'org.pantheon.desktop.gala.appearance'
Window manager warning: Log level 128: Settings.vala:163: Loading settings from schema 'org.pantheon.desktop.gala.keybindings'
Window manager warning: Log level 128: Settings.vala:163: Loading settings from schema 'org.pantheon.desktop.gala.shadows'
Window manager warning: Log level 128: Settings.vala:163: Loading settings from schema 'org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behavior'
Window manager warning: Log level 128: PluginManager.vala:132: Loaded plugin Mask Corners (libgala-maskcorners.so)
Window manager warning: Log level 128: PluginManager.vala:132: Loaded plugin Notify (libgala-notify.so)
Window manager warning: Log level 128: PluginManager.vala:132: Loaded plugin Zoom (libgala-zoom.so)
Window manager warning: Log level 128: Settings.vala:163: Loading settings from schema 'org.pantheon.desktop.gala.mask-corners'
Window manager warning: Log level 128: Preferences.vala:343: Loading preferences from file '/home/forcemagic/.config/plank/dock1/settings'
Window manager warning: Log level 16: Preferences.vala:186: '/usr/share/themes/elementary/plank/dock.theme' is read-only!
Window manager warning: Log level 128: Preferences.vala:343: Loading preferences from file '/usr/share/themes/elementary/plank/dock.theme'
Window manager warning: Log level 16: Preferences.vala:368: Missing key 'CascadeHide' for group 'PlankDrawingDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/themes/elementary/plank/dock.theme' - using default value
**
GnomeDesktop:ERROR:gnome-bg-slide-show.c:557:gnome_bg_slide_show_get_current_slide: code should not be reached
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"

** (polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:23710): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-hQz2kj7UDd: Connection refused
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"

** (process:23731): CRITICAL **: bluez.vala:104: GDBus.Error:org.bluez.Error.NoSuchAdapter: No such adapter

** (light-locker:23734): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-hQz2kj7UDd: Connection refused
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"

** (nm-applet:23728): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-hQz2kj7UDd: Connection refused

** (plank:23756): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-hQz2kj7UDd: Connection refused
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
initctl: UPSTART_SESSION isn't set in the environment. Unable to locate the Upstart instance.

(process:23720): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(process:23720): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(process:23720): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(process:23720): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(process:23720): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

** (slingshot-launcher:23760): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-hQz2kj7UDd: Connection refused

** (process:23709): CRITICAL **: volume_control_set_volume_internal: assertion '_tmp1_ == PA_CONTEXT_READY' failed

** (process:23709): CRITICAL **: file /build/buildd/indicator-sound-12.10.2+14.04.20140401/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/src/volume-control.c: line 1787: uncaught error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface (g-dbus-error-quark, 16)
gnome-session[23495]: WARNING: Application 'gala.desktop' killed by signal 6
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
Window manager warning: Log level 128: Settings.vala:163: Loading settings from schema 'org.gnome.desktop.background'
Window manager warning: Log level 128: Settings.vala:163: Loading settings from schema 'org.pantheon.desktop.gala.appearance'
Window manager warning: Log level 128: Settings.vala:163: Loading settings from schema 'org.pantheon.desktop.gala.keybindings'
Window manager warning: Log level 128: Settings.vala:163: Loading settings from schema 'org.pantheon.desktop.gala.shadows'
Window manager warning: Log level 128: Settings.vala:163: Loading settings from schema 'org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behavior'
Window manager warning: Log level 128: PluginManager.vala:132: Loaded plugin Mask Corners (libgala-maskcorners.so)
Window manager warning: Log level 128: PluginManager.vala:132: Loaded plugin Notify (libgala-notify.so)
Window manager warning: Log level 128: PluginManager.vala:132: Loaded plugin Zoom (libgala-zoom.so)
Window manager warning: Log level 128: Settings.vala:163: Loading settings from schema 'org.pantheon.desktop.gala.mask-corners'
Window manager warning: Log level 128: Preferences.vala:343: Loading preferences from file '/home/forcemagic/.config/plank/dock1/settings'
Window manager warning: Log level 16: Preferences.vala:186: '/usr/share/themes/elementary/plank/dock.theme' is read-only!
Window manager warning: Log level 128: Preferences.vala:343: Loading preferences from file '/usr/share/themes/elementary/plank/dock.theme'
Window manager warning: Log level 16: Preferences.vala:368: Missing key 'CascadeHide' for group 'PlankDrawingDockTheme' in preferences file '/usr/share/themes/elementary/plank/dock.theme' - using default value
**
GnomeDesktop:ERROR:gnome-bg-slide-show.c:557:gnome_bg_slide_show_get_current_slide: code should not be reached
gnome-session[23495]: WARNING: Application 'gala.desktop' killed by signal 6
gnome-session[23495]: WARNING: App 'gala.desktop' respawning too quickly
gnome-session[23495]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....

(gnome-settings-daemon:23633): Gdk-WARNING **: gnome-settings-daemon: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.


(polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:23710): Gdk-WARNING **: polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.


(light-locker:23734): Gdk-WARNING **: light-locker: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
nm-applet-Message: PID 23728 (we are 23728) sent signal 15, shutting down...
g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
Indicator-Power-Message: exiting: service couldn't acquire or lost ownership of busname
g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.

** (process:23731): CRITICAL **: service_on_name_lost: assertion 'connection != NULL' failed
g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.

** (process:23711): WARNING **: exiting: service couldn't acquire, or lost ownership of, busname
g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
Indicator-Datetime-Message: indicator-datetime exiting; failed/lost bus ownership
g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.

** (process:23709): CRITICAL **: indicator_sound_service_name_lost: assertion 'connection != NULL' failed
g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.

(nm-applet:23728): libappindicator-WARNING **: Unable to send signal for NewIcon: The connection is closed

(nm-applet:23728): libappindicator-WARNING **: Unable to send signal for NewStatus: The connection is closed

** (nm-applet:23728): CRITICAL **: nm_secret_agent_unregister: assertion 'priv->registered == TRUE' failed

(process:23709): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

Anyone please help, I'm really out of ideas here.

Comment: Work yourself up from the `gnome-session[23495]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....` line. It seems to suggest that the window manager Gala is crashing because the volume control has no PulseAudio context. It also doesn't seem able to load the File Chooser module. Consider to do a diff against a log from a working login to see how exactly it behaves different.

Comment: I'm kinda' a noob when it comes to X and audio and video, so, would you please "exactify" what you mean by `PulseAudio context` and I think I have an idea for the Gaia thing, but the file chooser module has been never loaded by any session.

Comment: If you cannot read or diff log files, there is no point in trying to diagnose and fix this manually. You might as well just reinstall in that case. The line that I refer to is `** (process:23709): CRITICAL **: volume_control_set_volume_internal: assertion '_tmp1_ == PA_CONTEXT_READY' failed`

Comment: I am using a fresh installation...

Comment: A fresh installation does not have multiple accounts.

Comment: I have my `/home/` partition separated, so my things can be kept safe in the event of a system upgrade. And I had debian installed then I switched to ElementaryOS

Comment: BTW, I know what you were referring to, but why does this only happen in this account?

Comment: There is probably something different in its directory in /home/; as to what, that's hard to tell without further debugging, because just a warning or error in a log could be the result of various differences

Comment: I found a file named `.pulse-cookie` would removing that help?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not, rename it before removing to be safe

Comment: Okay. I'm gonna backup then remove some suspicious files, then I'll report back

Comment: Alright, I moved the `.config` directory to a backup place where I can find it, and now it works! I think `xfce4` gave a hard time to ElementaryOS's Gala. Anyways, thank you @TomWijsman for helping :)

Comment: Sometimes looking from the "How would a reinstall fix this?" perspective instead of the "What does the log tell me?" perspective helps a great deal

Comment: True. Reinstalling this as many times as I'd wanted to wouldn't help this situation :P I'm just glad that it works now

Comment: Could anybody prepare some answer post out of these comments (if it's already solved), please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the best solution, but I'll post it anyway.

1. Move your `.config` directory to a safe place where you will find.
2. After that, try to login. If it fails, make sure that you move `.Xauthority` out of the way too.

This is how I got it working. If by any chance you want your config back for a specific program, just copy `safeplace/.config/your_important_program_here` back to its original place.